# Convert from DateTime to TimeStamp

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to convert a `DateTime` variable to `Timestamp`. My variable has the current format : `1/23/17 2:14:31 PM` and I would like it to be `TimeStamp` like so I can use it for Oracle SQL Developer. eg: `23-JAN-17 2.14.31.000000000 PM`.

I have tried to convert it like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O"));
```

but the output is nothing like `TimeStamp`:

```
2017-01-23T14:14:31.5838355Z
```

Comment: why cant you use a regular datetime for your SQL??

Comment: The person who made the Database made the column TimeStamp with that format and i can't change it.

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.80).aspx and one of them should answer your question. You might also want to check though whether the objects that manage your connection will do the conversion for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris that did actually solve my problem .

Comment: In the shown code, `new DateTime()` is not used and should be removed (for improved readability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
long epoch = (d.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss") + ":" + epoch);
```

Comment: Your `epoch` appears to be a "Unix" second count since the beginning of year 1970. ___What is the relevance?___ If needed, consider using `long epoch = ((DateTimeOffset)d).ToUnixTimeSeconds();` which is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToUniversalTime().ToString("hh-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.ffffff tt"));
```

Comment: The month at "PM" designator may depend on the culture, for example with `"es-ES"` (Spanish (Spain)) you may get `"23-ene.-17 02.14.31.000000000"` (`Jan` is `ene.`, and `PM` is nothing).